# CGPath vs UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgpath

Working with a piece of code that gets a CGPath in the following way:

```
let dirX = -spread
let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dirX, dy: dirX)
let cgPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
```

Is there a way I can just use that rect directly to get the CGPath?

I know there is

```
CGPath(rect: CGRect, transform: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>)
```

But I am not sure if it is simple to get the same CGPath directly with the init, because I am not sure how to use the UnsafePointer.

Explanations and Examples welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CGPath(rect: CGRect, transform: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>?)` and pass `nil` in `CGAffineTransform` as is optional

```
let dirX = -spread
let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dirX, dy: dirX)
let cgPath = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)
```

But this will not have any impact in your app functioning, even in the amount of code because anyway is one line

Comment: hahah so, the reason my code wasn't originally creating the same affect with the CGPath as it was with UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath was because of another bug that I found.  I was so perplexed XD marking as correct, because it is